# Comparing 2 dataframes with any number of columns and output in R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, subset

I am biologist and I am trying to use R to analyse my data.

I have my plates where I grew my bacteria on sertans position. So I have something like 2 tables where I pointed my bacteria is growing (1) or not (0).

```
# plate1
# K is a control column, A - E sample`s positions

K <- c(1, 0, 1, NA) 
A <- c(1, 0, 1, 0) 
B <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)
C <- c(0, 1, 0, 1)
D <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)
E <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)

plate1 <- data.frame(K, A, B, C, D, E)  # creating a dataframe with all observations for the first plate

# plate2

K <- c(0, 0, 1, NA)
A <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)
B <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)
C <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
D <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
E <- c(0, 1, 0, 1)

plate2 <- data.frame(K, A, B, C, D, E)  # creating a dataframe with all observations for the second plate.
```

I want to ask R two things:

1) to compare all the variables of columns A-E for two plates (dataframes)

2) give me an output where I have positions with `1` (growth) for the `plate1` and positions `0` (no growth) for `plate2`. I expect it like a new `dataframe` where I have `TRUE` and `FALSE` depending if the both positions match my conditions

I am sure that solution should be pretty simple but I tried to pass though the quiestions where people suggest to use `merge` function or different loops and did not succsed. Could you help me with this task, please? Can I do the same with multiple dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
plate1==plate2
#          K     A     B     C     D     E
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [4,]    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

and

```
plate1==1 & plate2==0
#         K     A     B     C     D     E
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,]    NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Wrap it in `as.data.frame` if you want a data frame.

Comment: Why mapply? `plate1 == plate2` ?

Comment: Oh, yeah that is very simple. I just confused by searching the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry guys, it is not working as I expected. I need the output where R gives me grow on the plate1 and not grow on the plate2. If I just compare the two dataframes, it will give me output that match two conditions: grow on the `plate1` and not grow on the `plate2` and versus versa (the opposite matches too). Sorry if I did not asked correctly

Comment: @makkreker `(plate1==1 & plate2==0) | (plate1==0 & plate2==1)` ? If you have new conditions, please update your post.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks, seems now look like it should be with conditions `plate1==1 & plate2==0`